# in an update, how to select an option from a select box?

Tags: php, html, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Good afternoon,

Using cakephp, how can I select a value in a select box in an update operation?

in the view I get the variables like this for example:

```
<?php $category = $itemEditar['Anuncio']['category']; ?>
```

and I need to select an option from a select box:

```
<select id="select_category" name="enquiry">
                    <option value="" >selecione</option>
                    <option value="Category1">Categoria1</option>
                    <option value="Category2">Categoria2</option>
                    <option value="Category3">Categoria2</option>
                </select>
```

to be an update operation, I need to mark the category that was saved in the database, and am not getting how to do this.

Comment: This isn't very clear, you want an option to be selected? Or you want to obtain the content of an option?

Comment: as an edit operation data in a form, I need to set an option in select box.
  This option is the one that comes from the database.

Comment: Your wording is unclear. You want to fill your option value via PHP?

Comment: yes, I have this variable in php. As in the above example it is called "$category".
  And must select an option from the select box.

Comment: Are you writing your select and options by hand? If so - you should be using the [form helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html) otherwise, your form and data structure will not match what Cake expects.

Comment: I do not use the helper to create the form, because I need to send data to jquery, and after some operations, sends them via ajax. And other details in the form.
  Not knowing how to do them, for not being an expert in cakephp, I did the way I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct answer is:

```
<select id="select_category" name="enquiry" >
                    <option value="Category1" <?php echo $category == "Category1"?" selected = 'selected'":"" ?> >Categoria1</option>
                    <option value="Category2" <?php echo $category == "Category2"?" selected = 'selected'":"" ?> >Categoria2</option>
                    <option value="Category3" <?php echo $category == "Category3"?" selected = 'selected'":"" ?> >Categoria2</option>
                </select>
```

Comment: Isn't that what Orangepill suggested with just one minor change of php tags positions?

Comment: don't forget the invalid attribute on the select.

Comment: yes it is similar, but for me, his answer did not work. Initially showed nothing, and after I change the order, and add echo, it worked.

Comment: probably the difference was he is using php < 5.3 and he has short tags disabled. You know <?= vs <?php echo

Answer (score 2):

You want to check the $category against each or the options and if they match set the selected attribute .

```
<select id="select_category" name="enquiry">
    <option value="" >selecione</option>
    <option<?= $category == "Category1"?" selected = 'selected'":"" ?> value="Category1">Categoria1</option>
    <option<?= $category == "Category2"?" selected = 'selected'":"" ?> value="Category2">Categoria2</option>
    <option<?= $category == "Category3"?" selected = 'selected'":"" ?> value="Category3">Categoria2</option>
</select>
```